# Join attributes by location very slow on QGIS 3.0

Tags: spatial-join, qgis-3

"Join attributes by location" is very slow on QGIS 3.0. I have tried it with a CSV file and also with a shapefile (point layer) and a grid (made of polygons). On QGIS3.0 it takes about 3 hours to complete, but on QGIS2.18.16 only 7 seconds. The calculated results look exactly the same. Am I missing something? Here are the screenshots of the setup (QGIS3.0 in picture 1 and 2; QGIS2.18.16 in picture 3):
[image: Qgis3.0]

[image: Qgis3.0]

[image: Qgis2.18.16]

Comment: Do you use spatial indexes, if so in both projects/versions?

Comment: @Stefan No, I used csv/shapefile directly without database, but now I tried with Spatialite files (used spatial index) also and it took approx 1.5minutes. A lot better, but still slower than with Qgis 2.18.16.

Comment: If you've found that running exactly the same process in QGIS 3.0 is slower than in 2.18, perhaps you should submit a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/issues

Comment: Did you submit a bug report?  If so, please link bug report here to make it accessible to users. If not, I think I am having the same issue: a simple join with very few features is taking a really long time.  I will make a few more tests and submit a bug report.